# Stop process on power button press

Tags: power-management, shutdown, command-line, timeout

I have an old ubuntu pc running a minecraft server, but I only want it on at certain times.

I want to be able to turn it on and off using only the power button. I am able to turn it on, but to turn it off requires the command 'stop' in the console to shut the server down.

Is there any way to tell it to enter the stop command when the power button is pressed, then after a time(a minute or so) turn the computer off?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Java is auto-killed by using a reboot function.

There is no need to run `stop`. All that command does is tell Java to gracefully (not forced) exit. When the server detects the graceful stop request, it kicks all users and ends the session.

When you press the power button, all processes are at first gracefully terminated, so it is the same as running the `stop` command.